# PHP cannot update record

Tags: php, sql, json

[image: How the table looks]I am coding a function to update the "status" attribute in the "users" table.
A status of 1 will mean that the user is online while a status of 0 will mean that the user is offline.

I trying coding a PHP file to set the status to 1 whenever a user logs in.

No matter what, the PHP call returns a 0 telling me that the update query failed to execute. Checked the codes multiple times but I can't seem to locate any errors.

Can somebody help me out?

```js
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

try{
 $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "classads");
 $userID = $_GET['userid'];
  
    $query = "update users set status = 1 where userid = " . $userID; 
 $result = $conn->query($query);

 if (!$result){
  $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";  
 }
 else {
  $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>1)) . "]";  
 }

 echo $json_out;

 $conn->close();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
 $json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
 echo $json_out;
}
?>
```

enter image description here

Comment: What's the datatype of the `userid` column?

Comment: Check you have a connection first http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Hi Rajdeep it's a primary key

Comment: @Dominic I mean to say, is `userid` column of type `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query from

```
$query = "update users set status = 1 where userid = " . $userID;
```

to

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE userid = '" . $userID . "'";
```

And later, use `->affected_rows` to check whether the UPDATE operation is successful or not.

Here's the reference:

- [mysqli::$affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: Affected rows (UPDATE): 0

Comment: @Dominic Do `echo $userID;` after this line `$userID = $_GET['userid'];` and see what you're getting.

Comment: It does echo the userid which I sent as parameter. But still returns a 0

Comment: @Dominic There are couple of things you need to debug. First check whether the database connection has established or not, like this: `if($mysqli->connect_errno){ echo "connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error; }`. Then check whether the row status is already set to 1 or not. Make use of [`mysqli::$error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to bebug the issue.